# Swift - UIToolbar with Done button for UIPickerView disappear on landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I made an `UIPickerView` as an input for a `UITextField` and implement a `UIToolbar` with a "Done" button. It works perfectly but when I switch to landscape mode on my iPhone the `UIToolbar` disappear. Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    thePicker.delegate = self

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 100/255, blue: 217/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Aceptar", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneClick))


    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    testTextField.inputView = thePicker
    testTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem when I add UIPickerView programmatically and add UIToolBar for the PickerView. Just need to add [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight] for the UIPickerView

```
self.thePicker.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
```